# How to troubleshoot Bluetooth connection with headset?

Tags: 11.10, pulseaudio, bluetooth

How can I troubleshoot or debug my Bluetooth headset connection in 11.10? I am able to successfully create a working connection to my Bluetooth headset. I am able to route the input and output to the headset in the "Sound Settings" menu. But after the first time I disconnect the headset, I can never reconnect the device. The only way to re-establish a connection is to delete the device and add it again.

I am using a Bluetooth usb dongle in a thinkpad t42 laptop. On the same machine, I am able to establish a working connection for my Bluetooth mouse that survives disconnects. In fact the mouse automatically re-establishes a connection to the laptop as soon as it's turned back on. I'm not so lucky with the headset, where I can't even re-establish the connection manually to the headset.

If there is a way to see what's happening when the headset tries to connect (e.g. log files or terminal command), I may be able to figure out why it is not successfully connecting.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find an answer to the original question specifically about how to troubleshoot a bluetooth connection. But, I did find a workaround solution to getting my bluetooth headset to consistently reconnect. Now that I have a workaround solution, I don't need to troubleshoot why the connection is not working.

In case you found this question because you are experiencing a similar connection issue with your Bluetooth EDR 2.1 device, I've posted the solution here: [Issues with Bluetooth Connections in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68939/issues-with-bluetooth-connections-in-11-10/104954#104954)