# Sennheiser MM450-X Bluetooth headset connected but not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headset

Sennheiser MM450-X Bluetooth headset gets recognized out of the box in Ubuntu 12.04 beta 64-bit. I used this workaround to get past the reconnection problem: [Issues with Bluetooth Connections in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68939/issues-with-bluetooth-connections-in-11-10/104954#104954)

Although the device is successfully connected I am not able to hear any sound into the headphones. Some interference noise is produced instead.

Comment: What sound profile did you set up your Bluetooth device?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "sound profile". Anyway I didn't set up anything, I left the default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by following the steps below:

- open the Sound Settings;
- select the device in the "Play sound through" pane;
- select "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)" in the "Mode" combo box;
- make sure the "Mute" checkbox is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Sound profile is the same as your *"Mode"* box.